# Other desktop apps bleed into a newly launched Text Editor

Tags: text-editor

Since upgrading to 18.04 (~2 years ago), I've had this weird desktop-bleeding problem on certain text-based applications including Text Editor, Meld, etc.

The problem looks like this:[image: Text Editor showing bleeding problem]

What happens is that when I launch the Text Editor, it inherits whatever it launched over (a Chrome browser open to Google, in this case.)  This has the appearance of that old Windows problem where you'd be running low on memory so the screen wouldn't quite refresh completely, but I have ample memory on this computer.  Make sense?  I don't even know where to begin to look for the problem.

Comment: Sometimes, the BIOS settings allow you to reserve certain amount of memory for graphics. See if you have that set to max. Also, are you are using integrated graphics or a dedicated GPU? What is your graphics chipset or card? Are you using Wayland of Xorg?